# Best convention of tcp-messaging

Tags: network-programming, pyqt, tcpclient, tcpserver, qtcpsocket

I'am using this message convetion  : %total_msg_length%|%msg_body% to recieve string data over tcp-sockets (python/pyqt). Is this is the good convetion, or should i try something else?

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon.

Another way than having a separator (like your `|`) would be to have the message length be fixed size, like always 4 or 8 characters. Then you can read 4 (or 8 or what you choose) to get the message size. The problem with this is that you have to make at least two calls to `recv`: One for the length and one for the body.